# Increasing application pool session time out not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, iis

In my project, i need to hold the session for 720 minutes also i am using forms authentication which is set 1440 (session*2) and when i am hosting this into IIS the session time out became default 20 minutes so i changed the application pool
Idle Time-out(minutes) to 720 . Which is suggested by many , then also the session time out is happening after 20 minutes .I dont know why this is happening . I am using IIS (7.5). Any one please help me. Its been more than one day I am searching through internet ,I cant find any proper answer
Nb: Forms authentication works just fine

Comment: What do the `Session.Timeout` property in the `Session_Start` and the attribute `<sessionState timeout="..." />` in your `Web.config` say? I don't know how these interact with the value set in your IIS application pool, but perhaps they are set to a lower one and lose your session data "earlier"?

Answer (score 6):

Website Session.Timeout will work only when it is less than the application pool session timeout value; because whenever the application pool session timeout value is reached, that particular application pool will be restarted. We have two things: the application pool that has its own session timeout value, and the web site that also has its session timeout value. Microsoft has given the parameter Session.Timeout to change the website session timeout value. not the application session timeout value. We have to understand one thing here: we have to make sure that the application pool session timeout value is always greater than the website session timeout value; only the will the Session.Timeout parameter work; otherwise, it won't. The reason is as follows: whenever the application session timeout is reached, the application pool will be restarted and because of that Session.Timeout of the website parameter won't work.

Please check these points and try

```
  Application Pool => Advanced Settings => Process Model => Idle Time-out(minutes)
    Sites => whatever web needs to be set => ASP => Session Properties => Time-out     remember to Apply the change
    Sites => whatever web needs to be set => Configuration Editor => system.web/sessionState => timeout    remember to Apply the change
    Sites => whatever web needs to be set => Configuration Editor => system.web/roleManager => cookieTimeout    remember to Apply the change
```

Comment: +1, although to me, it looks like the actual problem is the other way round: He set the application pool timeout to 720 minutes, but still the session is ended after 20 minutes. But your answer explains the correlation between the two "timeouts" which I wasn't sure about, so I learned something and (probably) a solution to the OP's problem is at hand as well: set the `Session.Timeout` property to be higher than 20 minutes (in the application or Web.config) as well, then it should be working.

Comment: May be problem with Forms authentication cookie time out. That needs to be checked if its lesser than 20 mins user will be logged out.

Comment: no webconfig session time out and application pool session time out both are same 720 minutes

Comment: Please check my updated answer. If that does not work try moving your session state into Sql  as shown in this link                                                 ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604). This should persist an IIS restart/app pool recycle etc.